# Bootstrap Columns Toggle with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with Bootstrap Columns Toggle that converts a 12 column grid into other two columns with 9 and 3 columns, and back to 12 columns again.

I have a prototype, but I can't seem to get it quite right. Here's the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/vq8rpx0f/1/).

To understand the issue, I have 3 different scenarios that are explained in the prototype that basically starts at 12 columns, gets toggled to 9 + 3 columns, and back to 12 columns.

The HTML code is as follow:

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h2 class="align-center">Current Prototype</h2></div>
   <div id="LeftColumn" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h4>Left Column</h4>
    <p>Currently is set to col-md-9, but it should initially be col-md-12 and be toggled to col-md-9 while maintaining its responsive properties.</p>
    <p><span class="strong">DESIRED RESULT:</span>Toggle the properties &lt;div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"&gt; to &lt;div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"&gt; when the "Toggle Right" column button is clicked while maintaining the existing functionality.</p>
    <div id="Bar" class="main-container collapse in">
      <a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" id="toggle-right">Toggle Right</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="RightColumn" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <div id="Foo" class="main-container collapse" style="border: dotted 1px green;">
Toggle Left Column <a href="#Bar" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>Additional content will be displayed in this column once triggered.
      <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The Javascript that needs attention is as follow:

```
$(".main-container.collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  //when a collapsed div is shown hide all other collapsible divs that are 
visible
  $(".main-container.collapse").not($(this)).collapse('hide');
});
$('#toggle-right').click(function(e) {
  var left = $('#LeftColumn');
  if (left.hasClass('col-md-9')) {
    left.removeClass("col-md-9 col-sm-9").addClass("col-sm-12 col-md-12");
  } else {
    left.removeClass("col-md-12 col-sm-12").addClass("col-sm-9 col-md-9");
  }
})
```

I would certainly appreciate any help and expertise you can provide with a custom **jsfiddle**.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is "not right" here ? It seems to do behave as you mentioned

Comment: It not working as desired. If you click the green "Toggle Right" the first time, you get the desired Right Column with a 3 column value while the Left Column would have a 9 column value. As you click the orange button, the Left Column still maintain the 9 columns but the desired experience is to change from 9 back to 12 columns.

Comment: Yes, this is because on "Toggle Right" you are adding the desired functionality from the function `$('#toggle-right').click(function(e) { .. }`(which is correct) but you are NOT adding the same functionality on "orange button". You need to add the same functionality(meaning call the same function) on orange button click as well. The "Toggle Right" button and "orange button" are 2 different buttons and hence you need to add the click events for both the buttons

Answer (score 0):

There are just couple of minor changes you need to do to toggle.

**Problem**: You are adding/removing the classes on the click of the `#toggle-right` button which is fine but you are NOT again doing the same on the next toggle button namely your `<a>`(yellow warning button) once your 12 columns get divided to 9 and 3.

```
<a href="#Bar" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

**Solution:**

All you need to do is call that same function which adds/removes the classes on the click of the `<a>` button as well. Firstly give a class or an id to the element to identify it.

```
<a href="#Bar" id="toggle-left" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Now you just need to add that new selector in your existing click function.

```
$('#toggle-right, #toggle-left').click(function(e) {
  var left = $('#LeftColumn');
  if (left.hasClass('col-md-9')) {
    left.removeClass("col-md-9 col-sm-9").addClass("col-sm-12 col-md-12");
  } else {
    left.removeClass("col-md-12 col-sm-12").addClass("col-sm-9 col-md-9");
  }
})
```

Comment: Almost there! The desired result is to toggle between the columns and not display the button.  I've changed the jsfiddle with the code you've provided, but the Right Column still shows when the orange button is clicked. Once one click the green "Toggle Right" button, the green button should disappear while the "Right Column" appears with the orange button. Once the orange button is clicked, the LeftColumn should take the 12 columns and the green button should reappear and the RightColumn should disappear until the green button is clicked again!

Comment: The above provided fiddle does NOT have what I suggested. Can you check this Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vq8rpx0f/10/ . This should work as you expected

Comment: Also the above suggestion is not to display or hide the button at all. It is to toggle the column widths. Like I mentioned the issue with your previous code is that you are not actually "toggling" in the first place. **You are adding the classes on "Toggle Right" button ONLY but as a matter of fact you need to do that on both "Toggle Right" AND the "orange button"**. Basically once your "Toggle Right" is hidden(showing as 9 columns) you are not checking again. You need to do this. Thats what this does `$('#toggle-right, #toggle-left').click(function(e) {`